# What's the meaning of kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little

Tags: ios, cgbitmapcontext

What are the meaning all of CGBitmapInfo constants？

```
typedef CF_OPTIONS(uint32_t, CGBitmapInfo) {
  kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask = 0x1F,
  kCGBitmapFloatInfoMask = 0xF00,
  kCGBitmapFloatComponents = (1 << 8),
  kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault = (0 << 12),
  kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little = (1 << 12),
  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little = (2 << 12),
  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big = (4 << 12)
}
```

Comment: follow this link https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgbitmapinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a description of the constants in the Core Graphic documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgbitmapinfo

[image]

Comment: I seen, but i don't understand what is '16-bit,little endian format. can you explain this for me? thanks.

Comment: @user6699034 try reading this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian

Comment: Wow, i finally understand it! For the working principle of the computer, i still need to learn more! thanks again!